# Using an array from a single cookie value as PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I'm trying to use this cookie - current=["1","2","4"] - as a usable array in PHP.
At the moment I can echo these values, but can't use them as an array. How would I convert these values into a usable PHP array?

```
$currentUsers = $_COOKIE['current']; 

echo $currentUsers;

print_r(array_values($currentUsers));
```

Comment: cookie values are inherently strings. they cannot be arrays, but you can store an encoded/serialized array-as-string in the cookie, then decode/unserialize.

Comment: `json_decode` or `unserialize`; tbh You could really create an object in PHP that implements `Serializable` and overload the `__serialize` and `__unserialize` correctly

Comment: Are you setting the array value or just accessing it? Because, if you are setting it, you could serialize it and then unserialize it as @Marc B said.

Comment: You'll want to use` explode`/`implode`, Cookies store strings so if you want to store an array -- store it as a comma separated list and explode by the comma when you want to turn it into an array.

Comment: @nikoslip I'm just accessing the array value, just accessing. Explode worked perfectly anyway

Comment: @Ianmc I know you accepted my answer and I'm thankful for that, but you should look at my other answer too. The one with preg_match_all, it's a much simpler solution. If you do not use only digits as users I can help you make it work. But it will be much easier to use preg_match_all than any other solution for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = explode(",",$currentUsers);
Var_dump($array);

Echo $array[0]; // 1
Echo $array[1]; // 2
Echo $array[2]; // 4
```

Edit: Not sure if the `"` is actually a part of the cookie values?
If it is you could use `str_replace('"', '', $currentUsers);` to remove the " from the values if you do it before the explode.

Edit2: as Ash pointed out I missed a part on the answer.
Here is the complete code:

```
$str = substr(str_replace('"', '', $currentUsers),1,-1);
$array = explode(",",$str);
Var_dump($array);

Echo $array[0]; // 1
Echo $array[1]; // 2
Echo $array[2]; // 4
```

Comment: `$array[0]` in your example would be: `current=["1"`; and `$array[1]` be `"2"` and `$array[2]` be `"4"]` - so it's not exactly what the OP wants

Comment: So is the [ and " part of the value? I thought it was just to make it clear what the value was. But I made an edit for the " because I noticed that too.

Comment: @ash Actually it'll just equal 1/2/3, PHP will parse out the "" when it needs to so you don't need the `str_replace`. At least it doesn't from my tests.

Comment: @Pigeon nope the value of `$_COOKIE['current']` is `current=["1","2","4"]` by what the OP says, I understand how Andreas assumed this was not the case.  PHP does not automatically universalize anything, not even x-www-form-encoded parameters.  Even if Andreas was correct with their assumption the OP did not make this clear.  Also a simple json_decode would have sufficed over `str_replace` and `explode`.

Comment: @Pigeon must be something weird going on between mine and your setup then because my tests yielded different results to that. *Edit* Oh.. You mean he was setting the cookie as a String with the value of `current=[]`... rather than an array with strings inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, if the values are always numbers as in the example:

```
preg_match_all("/(\d+)/", $currentUsers, $array);
```

Simple one liner. IF it's always numbers

Working example http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fuO
Click preg match all button first

Answer (score -3):

Use `eval()`

```
$current = [];
eval('$'.$currentUsers);
var_dump($current);
```

For those with lightweight downvote, the output:

```
[root@mypc]# php test.php
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
```

Comment: eval executes strings. an array in string context is the literal word `Array`, which is not exactly valid php code... All this does is spit out `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion ...` and `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting '(' ...`

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, but this is tested and working. And dont come with "eval is unsafe" and that kind of things, cause that is his own risk.

Comment: well, now you've added the `$`, which does change things, but doesn't change the end result. `$Array` still isn't valid php.

Comment: @MarcB yea, that happen when people like you downvote without even let me check if I pasted it properlty

Comment: I have to admit, I wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: @Nadir: even if `eval()` is only used at his own risk does that really make this a good answer?

Comment: @TomHaigh PHP comes with that function for a reason. If he sanitize and check the input before calling `eval()`, he should not have problems.

Comment: @Nadir "PHP comes with that function for a reason". There are lots of things in PHP that are there for a reason but are not necessarily a good idea. Even if `eval()` is there for a good reason I'm not convinced that reason is parsing strings.

Comment: @TomHaigh You might think so, but as I said, taking care of the input before using eval, you should not have to worry about it injecting code in your server.

Comment: PHP also comes with many ini configurations turned off for a reason, as well as a directive called `blacklist_fucntions` and eval should be one of them.  Give me an example where you need to use `eval`?  I bet in that case it's likely a cron which can have its own user restrictions and its own ini file - otherwise there is no reason for this.

Comment: @ash one example? This one for example? If you are an inexperienced php developer and all you have heard of eval is that is dangerous I understand that you think like that. But eval, in good hands, is fine

Comment: Eval has no place in any language. There is no need for it.  The correct answer here is serialisation I.e. `json_encode` and `json_decode`.  Sure, even if it was used with sanitised values it's a terrible usage it's merely a hack, you are the problem to the industry.

Comment: @ash wow... now I see what's your problem. Whatever, he has already an answer.